# release/5.0.0-CF1 Spartacus coping module from source results in error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I generate project using release/5.0.0-CF1 libraries and when I take order-history module from source code and paste it into my newly generated project (also adding it to spartacus-features.module.ts) it results with error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined' in order-history.component.html

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwIr3.png)

package.json and all dependencies are the same as in release.

Checked tsconfig.json if strictNullChecks is disabled on source, it's not but works.
When I disable it in my project, everything is ok :)

Comment: Hi @ALBA! I've just checked that such errors don't occur during the build process of release/5.0.0-CF1 branch. May I ask you for trying installing Spartacus into a new project using [this](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/develop/docs/self-publishing-spartacus-libraries.md) guideline and check whether you're facing the same issues?

Comment: Hi @PawełFraś, thanks for your reply,
I built release/5.0.0-CF1 also without any errors.
But when I install new project(project is build using verdaccio serving release/5.0.0-CF1 libs) as in guideline which you attached 
and copy order-history.module from source to my newly generated app, error TS2532 appears.

Comment: Can you help me understand what is the reason for copying the whole module to your project? Is this about creating a custom order history component? If not, this component should work OOTB when installed via schematics.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying customize component (could not be done through outlets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strict mode features for older spartacus modules were not enabled when they were developed. Therefore, there will be issues if you copy the component into your project and have strict checks enabled. You will need to disable them or improve them in your custom component.

Do you have [strictTemplates](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#strict-mode) enabled in your tsconfig.json? This is a feature that enforces null checking on templates that is not enabled by default in Spartacus for most libraries. When added to the src tsconfig in the cloned Spartacus lib, you will also start to see these template errors on build.

Comment: Hi @Caine Rotherham, thanks for your reply.
So if you clone sparatacus project on branch release/5.0.0-CF1 and use command yarn build:libs and afterwards yarn build:order it will pass. Then if you add variable and assign undefined into it in order-history-component.ts and use it in order-history-component.html and run yarn build:order again it will produce error TS2532 Object is possibly 'undefined'  which is telling me that in this module strictNullChecks are enabled

Comment: Do you have [strictTemplates](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#strict-mode) enabled in your `tsconfig.json`? This is a feature that enforces null checking on templates that is not enabled by default in Spartacus for most libraries.

Comment: That si the flag which causes the issue, thank you :)
@Caine Rotherham